# Usage of implies and equivalence in mathematics, confusion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

I am confused because I have seen implies and equivalent used interchangibly.  For instance,  I've seen

$$x-y=0 \implies x=y$$

And I've also seen

$$x-y=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$$

Are both of these statements correct?  Which one am I supposed to use?

I know that implies is true if the first statement is false, or both are true.  And equivalence is only true if both are true or both are false.  So is using them interchangibly okay for stuff like this?

Comment: If $P \iff Q$, then $P \implies Q$ is a fortiori true. If you use only the implication $P\implies Q$, then it may be advisable to write only that, but usually, it's not important whether you write $P\iff Q$ or $P\implies Q$ then. If you use both implications, you must write $\iff$ (provided the equivalence holds, of course), or list both implications $P\implies Q$ and $Q\implies P$ before each is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P \Longleftrightarrow Q$ is just short-hand notation for

$$ P \Longrightarrow Q \ \ \ \ \textit{ and }\ \ \ \ Q \Longrightarrow P.$$

So the difference between $P \Longleftrightarrow Q$ and $P \Longrightarrow Q$ is exactly the reverse implication $Q \Longrightarrow P$. In other words, whenever $P \Longleftrightarrow Q$ is true, so is $P \Longrightarrow Q$, but if only $P \Longrightarrow Q$ is true, it's not always the case that $P \Longleftrightarrow Q.$ That would depend on whether $Q \Longrightarrow P$ is true or not, which we can't tell just from $P \Longrightarrow Q$.

In the example you've given, both statements are correct, since $x=y \Longrightarrow x -y=0$, but although they are both true, they are not *logically equivalent*.

A counterexample is

$$ x > 0 \Longrightarrow x^2>0.$$

Since $x^2>0$ does not imply $x>0$, we can't just replace the above $\Longrightarrow$ with $\Longleftrightarrow$.

---

So in fact the answer to your question is that

$$ (P \Longleftrightarrow Q) \Longrightarrow (P \Longrightarrow Q)$$

is true,

but

$$ (P \Longleftrightarrow Q) \Longleftrightarrow (P \Longrightarrow Q)$$

is false.

Comment: So it is wrong to say that $x=y \Longleftrightarrow x-y=0$?

Comment: It is not wrong, but only for the particular example you gave. It may not be true for other examples because in general $\Leftrightarrow$ is not the same as $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different entities and should be treated as such. On your first sentence $x=y$ not necessarily implies that $x-y=0$. While on your second sentence saying $x-y=0$ is the same of $x=y$, because both are either true or false as you said, they are said to be equivalent.

Check [more info here](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/truth-tables/truth-tables.html)

As an exercise:

Every differentiable function is continuous. (differentiability $\Rightarrow$ continuity)

Try to find a continuous function that is not differentiable.